# PHP Warning: Missing argument 1

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I am getting this error in my php-fpm error log, and I was hoping one of you could show me how to fix my code.  Here's the error:

PHP message: PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for is_mx_handler::is_mx_handler(), called in /var/www/epiclasers.com/wp-content/plugins/devs-is-mx/devs-is-mx.php on line 37 and defined in /var/www/epiclasers.com/wp-content/plugins/devs-is-mx/devs-is-mx.php on line 16"

and here's my plugin PHP code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Dev's is MX ShortCodes
Description: If / Then shortcodes
Author: Devin Fleenor
Version: 1.0.0
*/

class is_mx_handler {

function generic_handler ($atts, $content, $condition, $elsecode) {
    list ($if, $else) = explode ($elsecode, $content, 2);
    return do_shortcode($condition ? $if : $else);
}

function is_mx_handler ($atts, $content="") {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        global $quick_flag;
        if(isset($quick_flag) && is_object($quick_flag)){
                if(($info = $quick_flag->get_info($ip)) != false){
        $code = $info->code;            // Country code: MX
        $name = $info->name;            // Country name: Mexico
        $latitude = $info->latitude;    // Country latitude (float): 45.1667
        $longitude = $info->longitude;  // Country longitude (float): 15.5
                }
        }

        if ($code == "MX") $ismx = "true";

        return $this->generic_handler ($atts, $content, isset($ismx), '[not_mx]');
}


}

$is_mx_handler = new is_mx_handler;
add_shortcode('is_mx', array($is_mx_handler, 'is_mx_handler'));
?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can't have more than one parameter in the method `is_mx_handler`. Try getting rid of `$content=""`; you can pass that as part of `$atts` instead.

Comment: I think you are missing () in the contructor. Try: $is_mx_handler = new is_mx_handler(); Also first parameter is not optional, it is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Dev's is MX ShortCodes
Description: If / Then shortcodes
Author: Devin Fleenor
Version: 1.0.0
*/

class is_mx_handler {

    function generic_handler($atts, $content, $condition, $elsecode) {
        list ($if, $else) = explode ($elsecode, $content, 2);
        return do_shortcode($condition ? $if : $else);
    }

    function __construct() {

    }

    function handle_mx($atts="", $content="") {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            global $quick_flag;
            if(isset($quick_flag) && is_object($quick_flag)) {
                if(($info = $quick_flag->get_info($ip)) != false) {
                    $code = $info->code;            // Country code: MX
                    $name = $info->name;            // Country name: Mexico
                    $latitude = $info->latitude;    // Country latitude (float): 45.1667
                    $longitude = $info->longitude;  // Country longitude (float): 15.5
                }
            }

            if ($code == "MX") $ismx = "true";

            return $this->generic_handler($atts, $content, isset($ismx), '[not_mx]');
    }


}

$is_mx_handler = new is_mx_handler();
add_shortcode('is_mx', array($is_mx_handler, 'handle_mx'));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_mx_handler($atts, $content="") {
```

-- that line is being called by --

```
$is_mx_handler = new is_mx_handler;
```

-- but two things are challenging here:

1. `is_mx_handler` expects  you to pass it two parameters, `$atts` (required), and `$content` (optional).  You can fix this by changing your function statement to:

   ```
   function is_mx_handler($atts='',$content="") {
   ```

   or by changing your instantiation to:

   ```
   $is_mx_handler = new is_mx_handler("",""); // passing in blank values for both arguments
   ```
2. Your constructor is currently named the same thing as your class. This functionality isn't really supported in `php4` and I recommend you move to using the following method name for your constructor : `void __construct()` per [the documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Hi John.  Thanks for your response!  I am very new to PHP, so if you could show me switch to the new void _contstruct() functionality that would be great - I'm not exactly sure how to change my code after reading that documentation page.